# Running extracted javascript using V8 with simulated DOM API (document.write contains html)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, v8, headless-browser

Well, I have to admit this is a very odd question but I do need a solution ASAP:

I am working on a JS testing project that requires the following working flow:

1. extract all the js from a webpage
2. use v8 shell or d8 to scan and parse those javascripts (do not need to actually execute it). Currently I don't want to use browsers such as chrome to do this, I only want to use v8 shell or d8.

The problem I have met is that the extracted JS contains DOM operations, including document.write(), which essentially contains a piece of html. I tried to search pure javascript implementation of DOM api without invoking third party libraries such as node.js, but no luck.

Since the document.write() contains html code, I also need a HTML parser, right? Is there anyway that I can make (2) working?  I noted that since I only need the scan and parse part of v8, a mock-up of the DOM api may work, but I don't know how to do this for document.write.

BTW, Is there any headless browser using V8 under linux?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use http://phantomjs.org/

Comment: AFAIK, phantomjs does not support v8.

Comment: Yep, guess not: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11074

Comment: I don't get it. If your goal is to "*scan and parse those javascripts (do not need to actually execute it)*", then you don't need to parse any HTML that is possibly embedded in them? So what are you actually trying to do?